# Why use a default value of None for this class initialiser?

Tags: python, tkinter

I tested the code in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129899/python-multiple-frames-with-grid-manager/6132876#6132876) and it works just fine.

The code creates a `Application` class like this:

```
class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
```

and creates an instance with:

```
root = Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
```

However, there is one  thing I do not understand in it: why the constructor takes as an argument a None object `def __init__(self, master=None):` but he calls the `Application()`  class he passes it a `root=Tk()` instance ?

Comment: `master=None` means if the calling party does not supply the parameter, assume it has the value None.

Comment: @SelçukCihan: the question is *why use that here*.

Comment: TkInter has a lot of unique conventions of its own. It's conventional to write `Frame` subclasses with `master=None`, even if you're only going to call them in one place in the code, and that one place is passing a value. But this isn't _completely_ useless; you might want to test the `Frame` somewhere besides the main app, or you might change your top-level code some day…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class copies the `Frame` constructor; it *too* takes an optional `master` argument. You don't *have* to pass in a master widget, even though here the code does pass one in. See the [*`frame` section](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/frame.htm) of [*An introduction to Tkinter*](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/):

> `Frame(master=None, **options)` (class)
>   A widget container.

The [`tkinter` documentation examples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html#a-simple-hello-world-program) include the same pattern:

> ```
> from Tkinter import *
>
> class Application(Frame):
>     # ...
>
>     def __init__(self, master=None):
>         Frame.__init__(self, master)
>         self.pack()
>         self.createWidgets()
>
> root = Tk()
> app = Application(master=root)
> ```

Doing so makes your code more flexible; you can now create an `Application` instance without a master, and pass it to code that takes any Tk object to bind at a later time.

Comment: I understand now your explanation. Thank you very much. But there is one last problem in this program: he declares `class  Application(Frame)` whereas he executes it by passing it a Tk() object and not a Frame. Why this contradiction works and Python accepts it ?

Comment: @Nakkini: `Application` is a subclass of `Frame`; that does not mean that the initialiser only takes frames. The two concepts are entirely orthogonal.

Comment: @Nakkini: you are confusing class inheritance with type declarations, I think. Python doesn't have any of the latter.

Comment: what is orthogonal concepts ?

Comment: @Nakkini: they are at right angles to each other; e.g. the two concepts are distinct and different.